# Get the first directory path from url in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to be able to get the first path directory from a URL in Laravel 5.1.  For example, take a look at the following url:

```
http://mydomain.co.uk/supervisor/add
```

From the above url, I want to return `/supervisor`

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use uri segment.

```
$segment = Request::segment(1);
dd($segment);
```

Hope it will help.Thanks